# Regex to eliminate a word

Tags: regex

I have strings like

```
BadRequestException("hello world")

BadRequestException(BadRequestException::$errors->message)

ConflictException(ConflictException::$errors->sldkf)

ConflictException("skdljf")
```

How do i add a regex that gets me these two:

```
ConflictException("skdljf")

BadRequestException("hello world")
```

I tried /Exception(/ to retrieve everything.

I could not figure out a way to eliminate those strings that contain "$errors"

I tried this:

```
/Exception(?!errors)/
```

But it did not work as per my requirements.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I used

```
Exception(?!.*::\$errors)
```